# Issue with creating clones of HTML div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create clones of a HTML div. The div has a label and two text boxes inside it. I need to change the label value of the newly created div.  Here is my code.

```
<body>
        <div id="PayDiv2">
            <label id="PayLbl2">Payment No 2: </label>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="text" /> 
        </div>

        <div id ="totPayForm" >
            <label id="totPayLbl">Total Payment: </label>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="text" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Add new one"  onclick="addNewField();
                    return false;">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Clone box" id="btn" />

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var i=3;
                //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $('#btn').click(function() {
                        var cloned = $('#PayDiv2').clone();
                        cloned.insertBefore("#totPayForm");
                        $('#PayLbl2').html("Payment No "+ i++ + ':');
                    });
                });

        </script>
    </body>
```

The problem is the place the newly created clones placed. First clone get placed before everything(even though I need to place it after the original div which I used to create divs. ) 
divs generated after that also get placed at first and, early divs goes down. It is hard to describe here. If you can be kind enough to run my code you will see what the issue is.

I have an another requirement to generate unique ids to cloned divs. Since I am new in `JQuery`, I found it difficult to generate id's.

I am pleased if you can help me in this case. Thank you all.

Comment: Cloning stuff with "id" values is problematic, as you have noted. When more than one element in a document has the same id, then things get weird.

Comment: please add dynamic id to the newly created div elements.

Comment: @VaibhavKatole as I mentioned I have problems with that also. Will Adding dynamic ids solve my issue?

Comment: @user3892439 yes, it will help you maintain your dynamically created divs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$('#PayLbl2').html("Payment No "+ i++ + ':');` it always changes the first element's label instead of the clone(because of the duplicated ids)...

so use class instead of id

```
<div class="PayDiv2">
    <label class="PayLbl2">Payment No 2:</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

then

```
var i = 3;
//When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var cloned = $('.PayDiv2').first().clone();
        cloned.insertBefore("#totPayForm");
        cloned.find('.PayLbl2').html("Payment No " + i+++':');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68jq2ks0/)

Comment: What will happen to CSS classes which have been already assigned to the div?

Comment: Add the class notation, wherever you have used '#' replace it with '.' for PayDiv2 and PayLbl2.

Comment: No I meant, There are css classes already assigned to divs. Will they get affected by this?

Comment: Please attach your css code in your question, so we can look into it.

Comment: @user3892439 you can have multiple class to a element like `<div class="PayDiv2 class1 class2">` - so add it as a new class

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by @Arun P Johny, set the div id `PayDiv0`

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var cloned = $('.PayDiv2').first().clone();
    // find total divs with class PayDiv2
    var noOfDivs = $('.PayDiv2').length;

    cloned.insertBefore("#totPayForm");

    // add new id to the cloned div
    cloned.attr('id', 'PayDiv' + noOfDivs);
    // find the label element inside new div and add the new id to it
    cloned.find('label').attr('id', 'PayLbl' + noOfDivs);

    cloned.find('.PayLbl2').html("Payment No " + i+++':');
});
```

this way you can add the dynamic ids to your elements.

Comment: I found this is not working. Could you explain me a bit what happens with newly added lines?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m7rdmuor/)

Make your HTML like below

```
<div id="PayDiv0" class="PayDiv0">
    <label id="PayLbl0" class="PayLbl2">Payment No 2:</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div id="totPayForm">
    <label id="totPayLbl">Total Payment:</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add new one" onclick="addNewField();
                    return false;">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Clone box" id="btn" />
```

And JS should be like this

```
var i = 3;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        
        var cloned = $('.PayDiv0').first().clone();
        var noOfDivs = $('.PayDiv0').length;
        cloned.insertBefore("#totPayForm");

        cloned.attr('id', 'PayDiv' + noOfDivs);
        cloned.find('label').attr('id', 'PayLbl' + noOfDivs);

        cloned.find('.PayLbl2').html("Payment No " + i+++':');
    });

});
```

Comment: Can't I start div Ids starting from PayDiv2. is it a must to start from 0 to work fine.

Comment: it's not must, you can start from 2, with some manipulation in code this can be achieved.

Comment: Why the id of the label does not get changed dynamically??

Comment: it's changing dynamically, see the DEMO link in my answer

Comment: Sorry, I have missed that. It is working. But how can I assign ids to input fields. There are two input tags. I need to assign ids to those two seperatly. When I give `cloned.find('input').attr('id', 'datepick_Pay'+ noOfDivs);` both input tags get affected.

Comment: give different class to input, and select it with class selector in jQuery. like this `cloned.find('input.datepick_Pay').attr('id', 'datepick_Pay'+ noOfDivs);`

Comment: is it possible to assign a javascript to newly created div?